# Casting in solidity is painful

Tags: solidity

I'm new to solidity, and have been struggling with what I thought should be very straightforward. I have a function to be called from the outside, and a bytes32 is passed in. I want to check whether the first bit is equal to 1, the second bit equal to 1, things like this. I can't do

```
bytes32 input;
if (input & (1<<1))
    ...
```

Because I'm told I cannot compare bytes32 and int const. I am also told there will be a problem turning what should be the resulting bytes32 into a bool for the if to check. How do I deal with this type insistence?

Answer (score 1):

```
uint digit_to_be_verified=0//0 for lsb
input == bytes32(1<< 4 * digit_to_be_verified )
```

change `digit_to_be_verified` variable to verify any bit